# improve my thumbnail generator?

Tags: php, gd

i have a [this function](http://snipplr.com/view/22288/resize-images/) which resizes images but the final quality looks blurred too much and not clear:

Any other class or a solution to improve the quality of thumbnails ?

Thanks

Other Note - i already changed the quality to 100 but nothing happened!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow.

Unless you provide some tests / screenshots we can't do much to help you, you seem to be using the right combination of functions (`imagecreatetruecolor` / `imagecopyresampled`) so my first guess would go to the `$quality` argument in `imagejpeg` and `imagepng` functions.

For `imagejpeg` I suggest you use `$quality = 90`. For `imagepng` should be `$quality = 9`.

You can also try sharpening the image by using a convulsion like this one right before saving the image:

```
ImageConvolution($dst_image, array(array(-1, -1, -1), array(-1, 16, -1), array(-1, -1, -1)), 8, 0);
```

For 3rdparty libraries I hear [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) and [Asido](http://asido.info/) are quite good.

Comment: hi, thanks for your nice answer, i looked at WideImage, looks pretty useful, but does it resizes and crops same time if the image is too long or wide ? i want the final size to be 40x40 so wide images wil be croped a bit from sides to fit thanks so much

Comment: @Marlene Brant: Yeah, you won't get the exact same functionality - I suggest you post some example images and respective output so that we can further help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to imagemagick, which is usually pretty prevalent on web-servers, you can save yourself a lot of headaches by using the buit-in `convert` command:

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd("env convert -thumbnail $format " . 
    $_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']; . " -interlace Line -enhance ".   $tmp_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately i don't have access to imageMagick.

Comment: imageMagick aka imagick is a superior choice, although if you can't update the PHP.INI then you can't access it.